# Using GParted to rescue data and format hard drive to NTFS

Tags: gparted, format

I'm having problems booting to Windows XP due to bad sectors on the hard drive. I've tried fixboot and fixmbr from the recovery console. That only made matters worse. Now I want to use GParted to attempt data rescue and format the hard drive to NTFS. Unfortunately, I get an error (Picture 2) when trying to recover my files, and the option to format the hard drive is grayed out. The only thing I can do is create a new partition.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

When I click "view" I get the "Unable to open the default file manager" error

Answer (score 2):

For recovering data use `Testdisk`: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
There is also a nice step by step tutorial: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

To format, make sure that the partition is not mounted by running on terminal the command `mount`. If it is mounted, umount it with `umount /mnt/path` and then format with `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdX`.

Comment: Post more info if possible about the errors that you might be having.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to recover data using GParted? Why is it not letting me?

If not: can I boot to Ubuntu Live CD and download the executable file for TestDisk?

Comment: GParted is not intend for recovering a partition AFAIK. Yes you can boot a live cd and install TestDisk.

Comment: But I can't even format it. I will try unmounting the hard drive as you said. Can this be done using the GUI? I'm not too good with running commands.

Comment: If you receive the "Unable to open default file manager" message then you can move the window aside and directly open the file manager using either the menu or icon on the desktop if you have an icon.  See the [GParted Manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-attempt-data-rescue) for more instruction.

Comment: Shutup and use **photorec**!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use " sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sda1 ".
Thanks to another answer here, not using the "-f", I lost all my data on my NTFS drive as it ZERO's out the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop background and open the file manager.
Copy the address that in your case is `/tmp/gparted-roview-MD2pwc` in the file manager address bar.

Note: i only found files from Windows partitions currently in use, for those of Ubuntu i got an error because the file system wasn' t correct, those partitions has been resized and deleted but not deleted in safe mode rewriting every bit of space.